# Paypal recurring payments using cmd=_xclick-subscriptions not returning transaction data to return url

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

I'm using a recurring payment feature on my website. Below is the code for the payment page.

```
<form id = "ofnForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXXXXXX@gmail.com">
    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">

    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->                    
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" class="payData" name="custom" value="1286">

    <!-- Specify URLs -->

    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='XXX.com/users/paymentAccountstatus/1286'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='XXX.com/users/paymentAccountstatus/1286'>
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value='XXX.com/users/paymentAccountstatus/1286'>                     
    <input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <img style="margin-top: 10px;" src="xx.com/image/paypal.png" id="paypal_img" class="paypal_img"/>
</form>
```

Onclick of the payment button system is redirecting to paypal website where the user is able to pay the amount. After payment succes paypal redirecting to the receipt page to show the payment detail. Below the payment detail there is a button called "return to marchant website". Onclicking to that button user is redirecting to my website but, I am not able to retrive any data from the return response.

Could anyone tell me why I am not able to receive any response from PayPal?

Any help is appriciable.

Comment: Once you are returned to the return URL, you need to send an HTTP request with your TX and AT [auth token]. Then you will receive file content, which you can loop over using the space character as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "Payment data transfer" enabled in https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website ?

It might not work with subscriptions

In any case, it's not very useful. The user may never return, either because they didn't click to return or because they were interrupted somehow.

---

If you need a reliable notification of the transaction information from subscriptions, set up a separate asynchronous listener for either webhook events, or the older Instant Payment Notification (IPN) message service